# Which directories to exclude before full Ubuntu synchronization?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, clone, mirror

I have two Ubuntu server which I want to synchronize so that I can run the second server when the first server is down. I want to do the synchronization using rsync. But I read, not all the directories (for example /boot and hardware specific files) are not supposed to be synchronized. Can someone tell me exactly which files and directories I need to exclude before doing full synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't backup things that aren't really files

```
/proc, /sys, /dev
```

You also may want to stay away from extra disks (like USB disks) or network mounts that you don't want being copied.

This question has more details

[Linux - What directories should I exclude when backing up a server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/74696/linux-what-directories-should-i-exclude-when-backing-up-a-server)